# Compare cardinality of two sets

Tags: cardinals

I had an argument about the following statement, which I think is wrong:

> One third of odd numbers (33.333%) will be divisible by 3.

1. Let $\Bbb{N}$ refer to the positive integers.
2. Let $\Bbb{O} := \{o | o = 2n-1; n \in \Bbb{N}\}$, the set of odd numbers.
3. $2n-1$ is a (trivial?) bijective function to $\Bbb{N}$.
4. Thus $\Bbb{O}$ is countably infinite.
5. Thus $|\Bbb{O}| = |\Bbb{N}| = \aleph_{0}$.
6. Let $\Bbb{M}(m) := \{o | o = 2n-1 \land o\mod m = 0; m,n \in \Bbb{N}\}$, the set of odd numbers which are divisible by $m$ without remainder.
7. The additional condition $ o\mod m = 0$ does not remove the bijective property of the odd numbers, as I think we can do a kind of Hilbert Hotel here: For $\Bbb{O}$ we have
   $1 \to 1$,
   $2 \to 3$,
   $3 \to 5$,
   $4 \to 7$,
   $5 \to 9$,
   $6 \to 11$,
   $7 \to 13$,
   $8 \to 15$,
   $7 \to 17$,
   ..
   For e.g. $\Bbb{M}(3)$ we have
   $2 \to 3$,
   $5 \to 9$,
   $8 \to 15$,
   ..
   which can be renumbered as
   $1 \to 3$,
   $2 \to 9$,
   $3 \to 15$,
   ..
8. Thus $\Bbb{M}(m)$ is countably infinite.
9. Thus $|\Bbb{M}(m)| = |\Bbb{O}| = \aleph_{0}$.
10. The quoted statement is now in those terms $\frac {|\Bbb{M}(3)|}{|\Bbb{O}|} = \frac {\aleph_{0}}{\aleph_{0}} = 1 \neq \frac {1}{3}$, which is a contradiction.

Where am I wrong? Or where is more precision in my argumentation needed?

Comment: It's difficult to work with infinities this way.  To get at the sort of thing you (probably) are looking for, take a limit.  Show that for odd numbers with absolute value $<N$ roughly $\frac 13$ of them are divisible by $3$ and that this becomes exact in the limit.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  For an infinite set, its cardinality can be the same as that of a subset

Comment: You might find the concept of “natural density” interesting. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density.

Comment: Okay, so 10) is out of question and I need to look into the limit/density argument. But to get my wording and math correct: 3) am I allowed to call the generator function trivial? Is the Hilbert Hotel approach in 7) the correct argument or do I need to go for something different here? Thus, is 9) correct?

Comment: @ste5an everything except for 10 looks good to me. Your reasoning shows that you have to be careful doing arithmetic with cardinals and talking about densities of infinite subsets of a set

Answer (score 1):

In step 6, allowing "$m,n\in\mathbb N$" is too permissive. Consider that $\mathbb M(2)$ is the empty set! It would be better to require that $m$ is an odd prime in the definition, or at least that $m$ is an odd number. Then you can reason about general $\mathbb M(m)$ by calling on the Chinese remainder theorem.

In step 7, you're right that we can "do a kind of Hilbert Hotel", but you might want to write down the explicit bijection $\mathbb N\to\mathbb M(m)$ instead of hand-waving it. It's a simple enough formula, and proving that it works will help to show what kind of condition you need on $m$.

In step 10, as the comments say, that sort of division isn't going to work. Cardinal arithmetic is tricky; for example, $3\aleph_0=\aleph_0$.

Comment: thx, that's helpful as the greater discussion was indeed about primes.